# Symfony 3 consume api data without using ajax or Angular

Tags: php, rest, symfony, http, templates

I'm working on a rest API to sell as SaaS. I already have most of the functions that interest me (integration with Mercadolibre a Spanish web site, market payments, google maps, social networks and also the accounting management part).

But now I want to add the possibility for the client to have a FrontStore where they can offer services with a few default templates that feed on API resources.

The issue is that I do not know how I can keep it isolated from the API code without using Angular, as Angular for websites affects a lot to the SEO. (the control panel and the mobile app did not have problems because I asked for everything by Ajax but those two things are not customizable)

So I do not know what to do.

Summarizing the question is: Since they could give access to templates or themes but not to the backend, it will be on another server.

I had planned to make 1 instance of the program for each client, but I do not want to do that since I did multi-company and I want to take advantage of it.
But I want to offer my 10 basic templates, the service to make a premium and also the possibility of the client to upload their own page. I hope I was clear.

I work with Synfony 3.0.0 and Angular 1.6 on a LAMP platform.

I need some idea to make possible get data from another server that have the rest API and use it just for a website like showing products or that kind of things. But without using Ajax or Angular templating.

[image]

I leave you a image to clarify. The left side is the private part, this is not customizable for the client, the right side is the web site and I want make it customizable by templates consuming the data from the API.

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand all but if you need to consume API without ajax or angular, you can use [guzzle http](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/) to create a client class that contains all your webservices (like showing products or that kind of things). This a [tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/creating-rest-api-in-php-using-guzzle-d6a890499b02) how can use it. Hope help !

Comment: what part do you dont understand i have 1 api rest used by 1 control panel, 1 mobile app, and 1 point of sales desktop app. I want to use the api to in a website like a ecommerce in other domain thats better explain?